# Bash Shell - Return substring after second occurrence of certain character

Tags: linux, bash, sed, substring

I need to return everything after a delimeter I decide but still don't fully know how to use sed.
What I need to do is:

```
$ echo "ABC  DE,FG_HI J,123.XYZ-A1,DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS,,," \
  | sed <some regexp>
```

For this example the return should be (substring)everything after the second comma:

```
123.XYZ-A1,DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS,,,
```

I can do this with cut like this:
`echo "ABC  DE,FG_HI J,123.XYZ-A1,DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS,,," | cut -d',' -f 2-`

but I've been told cut is slower than sed...

Can some guru who has them (and wants to... :) ) give me a few minutes of his time and advice me please?
Thanks!
Leo

Comment: I don't know if `cut` is slower than `sed` in this specific case, but I can tell you that `cut` is not "slower than `sed`" enough to make any practical difference. If speed was that important, you wouldn't be processing this in Bash, right?

Comment: Thanks Will, where would I be processing it then if speed was paramount?

Comment: If speed really matters, you would write it in C, and it might be .002% faster than using `cut`, which in turn will be much faster than `sed`.

Comment: "If you need to ask, then it's fast enough", but that said, look at it this way: `sed` and `cut` are written in C. They are both designed to handle a wide variety of inputs, and produce a wide variety of outputs. If you were to write a tool in C, then you could simplify your code and optimise for the specific case that you need to handle. This would indeed be faster. It would not be faster-enough to be worth the effort.

Comment: Turns out the C implementation is much faster than cut. nearly 3.7 times faster on 100000 lines of input.  I'm mightily surprised that cut performs so poorly.  I would be more surprised if even a 4x speed up is worth the 10 minutes it will take to implement in C (.089 seconds compares poorly to .024s, but is still fast enough for most situations).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my experience `cut` is always faster than `sed`.

To do what you want with `sed` you could use a non-matching group:

```
echo 'ABC  DE,FG_HI J,123.XYZ-A1,DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS,,,' |
  sed -r 's/([^,]*,){2}//'
```

This removes the first two fields (if the fields do not contain commas themselves) by removing non-comma characters `[^,]` followed by a comma twice `{2}`.

Output:

```
123.XYZ-A1,DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS,,,
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Thor! This does exactly what I wanted with sed. I will try both with some big files to see which one is faster.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try doing the extraction in `bash` without spawning an external process at all:

```
$ [[ 'ABC  DE,FG_HI J,123.XYZ-A1,DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS,,,' =~ [^,]*,[^,]*,(.*) ]]
$ echo "${BASH_REMATCH[@]}"
123.XYZ-A1,DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS,,,
```

or

```
$ FOO='ABC  DE,FG_HI J,123.XYZ-A1,DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS,,,'
$ echo ${FOO/+([^,]),+([^,]),}
```

or

```
$ IFS=, read -a FOO <<< 'ABC  DE,FG_HI J,123.XYZ-A1,DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS,,,'
$ echo ${FOO[@]:2}
```

(Assuming this is for a one-off match, not iterating over the contents of a file.)

Answer (score 0):

This method is by find the index of second occurrence of a character and using bash substring to get the required result

```
input="ABC  DE,FG_HI J,123.XYZ-A1,DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS,,,"
index=$(($(echo $input| grep -aob '/' | grep -oE '[0-9]+' | awk 'NR==2') + 1))
result=${input:$index}
```